# Remove empty arrays from PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am using PDO in order to select some values from my database. 
 For each iteration of my $teachArray, I store the selected value into my $language_id variable. 
 However, I am also storing some empty arrays which is not my intention.

I would like to know if it is possible to exclude or just get rid off empty arrays inside my php variable.

Here is my simple query.

```
$sqlFindId = "SELECT language_id
              FROM language_skill
              WHERE person_id = :person_id AND language_learning = :language_learning AND language_id = :language_id";

             foreach ($teachArray as $dataTeach)
             {
                 $query = $handler->prepare($sqlFindUser);
                 $query->bindValue(':person_id', $_SESSION['person_id']);
                 $query->bindValue(':language_learning', 1);
                 $query->bindValue(':language_id', $dataTeach);
                 $query->execute();
                 $language_id = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                 print_r($language_id);  
             }
```

I use print_r on my query in order to see my variable contents.

Here are the results of my print_r. I want to get rid of the first and last arrays which are empty. It can be noted that these empty arrays can appear anywhere in my print_r.

```
Array ( ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [language_id] => 13 ) ) Array ( )
```

I have tried using

```
$array= array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $language_id));
```

but it gives the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         foreach ($teachArray as $dataTeach)
         {
             $query = $handler->prepare($sqlFindUser);
             $query->bindValue(':person_id', $_SESSION['person_id']);
             $query->bindValue(':language_learning', 1);
             $query->bindValue(':language_id', $dataTeach);
             $query->execute();
             $language_id = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
             if ( count( $language_id ) != 0 ) {
                 print_r($language_id);  
             }
         }
```

Hope it can helps :)

Comment: What kind of NoEmptyArray type? Is it multidimensional or just regular array?

Comment: @Ukasyah You will need to use an at-sign to notify Viteazul of your message (like I have just done to you).  You can modify your comment for the first 5 minutes.  Just add `@Vitezaul` to your previous comment.

Comment: @Ukasyah I think its fine now, I did :             
                             `$NoEmptyArray_language_id = $language_id;`
                            `print_r($NoEmptyArray_language_id);`